# Sort non-letter characters

Tags: linux, string, sorting, ascii

I am using `sort` command in Linux to sort strings. The problem is that my strings contains non letter characters such as `!{%^$@#)(`.

I have noticed that `sort` in Linux ignores these characters and sort based on letters only. However, I want to sort based on these characters' ASCII code also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a locale of "C" to force bitwise collation.

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort ....
```